# Why do I often see male robins with female robins?

Tags: zoology

Even when it is not breeding season for robins I still often see male robins with female robins. But why?

I know that the male robin often chirps to find female robins within his territory. I also know that the male robin puffs his chest to try to impress a female robin.

But I have seen out in the country that even during the fall and late summer the male robins are still with female robins. I don't know whether it is to raise their fledgling chicks or what because only in videos and pictures have I seen robin chicks and robin eggs.

Comment: Male and female robins have the same habitat, so it is not surprising you see them both in the same area. Robins do not mate for life, but do stay together during the full breeding season, which may include 2-3 nestings. Sometimes in the spring a particular male and female will return to the same territory, and may end up staying together for another year, especially if they successfully raised chicks together the previous year.

Comment: @MattDMo You can probably expand your comment into an answer if you want.

Comment: This has since been asked and answered at http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/10290/66 - dunno if you want to close it here?